# How to split array from json rewsult in 2 new arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am not a coder but trying to fix an app, please help me to solve this trivia

I have this array:

```
{[[1525711250000,398],[1525711260000,408],[1525711270000,null], 
[1525711280000,410],[1525711290000,396],[1525711300000,380], 
[1525711310000,372],[1525711320000,366],[1525711330000,355], 
[1525711340000,355],[1525711350000,357],[1525711360000,349], 
[1525711370000,355],[1525711380000,355]]}
```

How do I get 2 new arrays like this?

```
new_array1 = {[1525711250000,1525711260000,152571127000,1525711280000,1525711290000....]}

new_array2 = {[398,408,null,410....]}
```

thanks a lot

Comment: Using a plain old `for` loop: iterate over the array, and fill 2 other arrays, then return the latter two.

Comment: what you've shown and what you require are actually invalid in javascript - due to the arbitray random `{}` enclosing the array - perhaps that's why you haven't been able to write any code at all - note: StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to 
[try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're using ES use the map function on the original array like this:

```
new_array1 = items.map(item => item[0])
new_array2 = items.map(item => item[1])
```

here the items array is the given array

Comment: This taught OP nothing.